# How Can I Use Data Validation On Single or Multiple Email Addresses That are Comma Separated?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for a custom formula for a cell data validation rule. I need users to be able to write in a single e-mail address, and `=IsEmail()` works great for that. However, I also need them to have the ability to list multiple e-mail addresses that are comma separated in the same cell.

Ex. email1@gmail.com,email2@otherdomain.net

Is there an addendum that I can do this type of validation to get it to work?

Any help/advice you all could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to check if all comma separated emails in a particular cell is valid email address, in this case, cell A1

```
=if(countif(arrayformula(ISEMAIL(split(A1,","))),False)>0,False,TRUE)
```

The function `split(A1,",")` split all comma separated emails into an array of emails and `arrayFormula()` feeds individual values to the `isEmail()` function. Which returns a array of `TRUE` or `FALSE` values. This array is counted to check if any of them have the value `False` using `countif()`. If yes then the `if()` returns `False` suggesting one of the emails is wrong. Else will return `True` suggesting all the entered emails are valid.

Comment: that works perfectly! I understand exactly how that works, and it's definitely in the knowledge bag. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me as well! Do you know if there is a way to prevent empty strings from being considered valid, e.g. ex1@gmail.com,,ex2@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

This was almost exactly what I was looking for, thanks. However, in my case I found it useful to slip in a "trim()" wrapped around the split as the email addresses were separated by commas but also had leading spaces which triggered a "FALSE".

```
    =if(countif(arrayformula(ISEMAIL(trim(split(C21,",")))),False)>0,False,TRUE)
```